# Are there standard test data sets for English stemmers / lemmatisers?

Tags: computational-linguistics, reference-request, online-resources

There is a lot of easily located material online which describes [stemmers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) or provides implementations. There's a bit of discussion of metrics for quantifying how effective they are, and I've even found an [evaluation program](http://www.comp.lancs.ac.uk/computing/research/stemming/Links/program.htm). What I can't find anywhere is some manually tagged data for use in such evaluation.

Are there standard test data sets for English stemmers? (Test data sets for lemmatisers would obviously also serve). Are they freely available online?

Comment: Why do you want tagged data? You can use normal corpora.

Comment: @Adel, I think you must understand something different by "*tagged data*" to what I'm trying to communicate. What I wanted was essentially a list of pairs of the form (word, lemma) which would allow me to test whether the stemmer gave the same output for every word which shares a lemma.

Answer (score 3):

There is a list of vocabulary and the output from testing the snowball algorithm available at the Snowball Github page, though it is not precisely human tested but it's good for testing you stemmer.

It supports the following languages:

```
arabic  
danish
dutch
english
finnish
french  
german  
hungarian   
italian     
kraaij_pohlmann     
lovins
norwegian
portuguese 
romanian 
russian 
spanish 
swedish
tamil
turkish
```

You can find this dataset at: https://github.com/snowballstem/snowball-data